# What happens when we run the "Win+R"?

Tags: windows

I want to know the essence about <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and what does the PC do when we run the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>?

I search "run" in Windows, and open the file path, it's `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\Run.lnk`. It hasn't got a target file path, but other files in the same directory have. I feel its uniqueness from this.

Can someone provides me with some relevant documents or explain it directly to me?

Comment: Can you not search for the relevant documents you need on your own?  I just use Win+r as it comes.

Comment: Win+R is no different than any keyboard shortcut, really. A program (explorer.exe) handles it in an unremarkable way and displays a window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `run.lnk` you reference *is a convenience* and not the source of the run dialog.

The run dialog is produced directly by Explorer.exe from resources pulled from both explorer.exe and shell32.dll.

Some "special links" have the ability to invoke things in the explorer directly.  In the past, this is done through invoking a COM object, but this bugger looks a little different.

If we disect the `run.lnk` file with a hex editor, we see this:

[image]

This is not a typical shortcut.
I am too lazy to disect the actual format to see if it fits with the LNK file specification but I suspect that it does not.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice answer for the question at hand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I want to know : )